# cmd.ExtraFiles fails when trying to pipe to it

Tags: go, pipe

I'm trying to have a pipe go to the `cmd.ExtraFiles`

I currently have the error saying

```
cannot use cmdstdout (type io.ReadCloser) as type []byte in argument to pipeR.Read
cannot use cmdstdout (type io.ReadCloser) as type []byte in argument to fd3.Write
```

This is the gocode I have thus far

```
cmd2 = exec.Command("-i", "pipe:0", "-i", "pipe:1")
cmd1 := exec.Command("command", "-o", "-")
pipeR, pipeW, _ := os.Pipe()
cmd2.ExtraFiles = []*os.File{
    pipeW,
}
cmd1.Start()
cmd1stdout, err := cmd1.StdoutPipe()
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("pipeThruError: %v\n", err)
    return err
}
fd3 := os.NewFile(3, "/proc/self/fd/3")
fd3.Write(cmd1stdout)
pipeR.Read(cmd1stdout)
pipeR.Close()
pipeW.Close()
fd3.Close()
cmd3 = exec.Command("command", "-o", "-")
stdin, stdinErr := cmd3.StdoutPipe()
if stdinErr != nil {
    log.Printf("pipeThruFStdinErr: %v\n", stdinErr)
    return stdinErr
}
cmd3.Start()
cmd2.Stdin = stdin
```

EDIT: Added full scope
The goal is to have cmd2 accept input via cmd3 by `Stdin`, and have cmd1 output piped via `ExtraFiles`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types don't quite line up here. Specifically,

```
cmd.StdoutPipe
```

returns an `io.ReadCloser`

whereas

```
pipeR.Read
```

is expecting an `[]byte` as input.

I believe you are ultimately looking to utilize the [Read](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Read) and [Write](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Write) functions of the [os package](https://golang.org/pkg/os/) to accomplish your task as shown below:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("command", "-o", "-")
    pipeR, pipeW, _ := os.Pipe()
    cmd.ExtraFiles = []*os.File{
        pipeW,
    }
    cmd.Start()
    cmdstdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("pipeThruError: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    buf := make([]byte, 100)
    cmdstdout.Read(buf)

    pipeR.Close()
    pipeW.Close()
    fd3 := os.NewFile(3, "/proc/self/fd/3")
    fd3.Write(buf)
    fd3.Close()
```

}

Comment: So it compiles, but when I run it the cmd2 doesn't see the input

Comment: That makes sense given the way that pipes work. Reads from `pipeR` return bytes written to `pipeW`. In other words, we ought to be writing something into `pipeW`

Comment: right, but that's where I get confused, i was trying to do that with `fd3.Write(cmdstdout)` in the original question

Comment: I think that ought to work, except you gotta do the write before the read and then utilize the read to get the data.

Comment: I went ahead and updated the question, trying to write before the read, as well ad better named variables, but it still does not find the stream

Comment: could you update it one more time with the full source so I could see how `cmd2` is declared

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187464/discussion-between-daplho-and-nadermx).